# Is there a way to use java to execute a series of command line

Tags: java, visual-c++, command-line

I'm looking for a way to compile visual studio c++ project in java. I know it's a bit strange to do it this way. but I'm doing a evolutionary algorithms. So Java is creating c++ code and compile it in Java not c++. I just need to automate it, so I don't have to copy the c++ code and paste it in .NET and click compile it.

So I'm looking for a way to execute series of command lines and display the result in eclipse console. Can I do that?

First I need to setup Visual Studio environment, so I need to run this batch first C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat and then change directory to the c++ project and compile the project by using "cl.exe" and then "link.exe". They need to be executed in a specific order.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you need to do anything in Visual Studio for this. You can use Java to call executables and the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler can be executed from the command line and passed in parameters and files to compile as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Create a batch file and run it by using ProcessBuilder.

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class DoProcessBuilder {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       if (args.length <= 0) {
         System.err.println("Need command to run");
         System.exit(-1);
       }

       Process process = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
       InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String line;

       System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", 
          Arrays.toString(args));

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easy way is as follows:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "yourcommand.exe", "argument1", "argument2", ... };
Process p = Runtime.exec(cmd);
```

You can also find other variation [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html), (eg by specifying environment and working directory too